# LINQ - if condition

Tags: linq, if-statement, linq-to-sql

In code, the commented part is what I need to solve... Is there a way to write such query in LINQ? I need this because I will need sorting based on Status.

```
var result = (
     from contact in db.Contacts
     join user in db.Users on contact.CreatedByUserID equals user.UserID
     join deal in db.Deals on contact.ContactID equals deal.ContactID into deals
     orderby contact.ContactID descending
     select new ContactListView
     {
         ContactID = contact.ContactID,
         FirstName = contact.FirstName,
         LastName = contact.LastName,
         Email = contact.Email,
         Deals = deals.Count(),
         EstValue = deals.Sum(e => e.EstValue),
         SalesAgent = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName,
         Tasks = 7,
         // This is critical part
         if(Deals == 0) Status = "Prospect";
         else
             Status = "Client";
         // End of critical part...
     })
     .OrderBy(filterQuery.OrderBy + " " + filterQuery.OrderType)
     .Where(filterQuery.Status);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Status = (deals.Count() == 0 ? "Prospect" : "Client")
```

This uses the ["Conditional operator"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

> The conditional operator (?:) returns
>   one of two values depending on the
>   value of a Boolean expression.

**Edit:** You can make combinations like this:

```
Status = (deals.Count() == 0 ? "Prospect" : (deals.Count() == 1 ? "Client" : "Other"))
```

In this case your are using `deals.Count(`) a lot, so you can store the result in a temporary variable using the LINQ `let` syntax:

```
var result = (
   from contact in db.Contacts
   join user in db.Users on contact.CreatedByUserID equals user.UserID
   join deal in db.Deals on contact.ContactID equals deal.ContactID into deals
   let dealCount = deals.Count()
   ... // Continue here
     Status = (dealCount == 0 ? "Prospect" : (dealCount == 1 ? "Client" : "Other"))
```

Comment: that's it, except it has to be deals.Count() instead of Deal. What if I have more than two cases, is there possibility to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: @ile - Absolutely, you just need to use some parenthesis..
Status = (Deals.Count() == 0 ? "No deals" : (Deals.Count() == 1 ? "One deal" : "Many deals"))

Answer (score 4):

```
// This is critical part
Status = deals.Any() ? "Client" : "Prospect"
// End of critical part...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ar result = (
     from contact in db.Contacts
     join user in db.Users on contact.CreatedByUserID equals user.UserID
     join deal in db.Deals on contact.ContactID equals deal.ContactID into deals
     orderby contact.ContactID descending
     select new ContactListView
     {
         ContactID = contact.ContactID,
         FirstName = contact.FirstName,
         LastName = contact.LastName,
         Email = contact.Email,
         Deals = deals.Count(),
         EstValue = deals.Sum(e => e.EstValue),
         SalesAgent = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName,
         Tasks = 7,
         // This is critical part
         Status = deals.Count()==0 ? "Prospect" : "Client",
         // End of critical part...
     })
     .OrderBy(filterQuery.OrderBy + " " + filterQuery.OrderType)
     .Where(filterQuery.Status);
```

Comment: `deals.Any()` would be better  :)